# Index on sort column

Tags: sql-server, sorting, indexing

I have Int type Sort column where I enter numbers to set records sort order. Do I need to index such columns for better performance?

Comment: Just in case you'd like to learn more about indexing: [SQL Indexing Tutorial](http://use-the-index-luke.com/?dbtype=sqlserver)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use this column in your SELECT statement, especially in WHERE, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, TOP and DISTINCT clause - you need to index this field.
Please read this article http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/optimizing-indexes-general/ to read more about indexes and perfromance.

Comment: Link out of date